# Dividing by Rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Stage'] = ['A','B','A','B']
df['Value'] = ['3','0','2','4']


Stage   Value
    A       3
    B       0
    A       2
    B       4
```

I want to be able to transform it into something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Stage'] = ['B/A','B/A']
df['Ratio'] = ['0','2']


Stage   Ratio
  B/A       0
  B/A       2
```

Is this possible in pandas?

Answer (score 1):

You can `unstack` and `eval`:

```
df['Value'] = df['Value'].astype(int)
df['group'] = df.groupby('Stage').cumcount()
df.set_index(['group', 'Stage'])['Value'].unstack().eval('B/A')
```

output:

```
group
0    0.0
1    2.0
Name: Ratio, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```py
df["Value"] = df["Value"].astype(int)

df_out = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Stage": "B/A",
        "Ratio": df.loc[1::2, "Value"].values / df.loc[::2, "Value"],
    }
)
print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
  Stage  Ratio
0   B/A    0.0
2   B/A    2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df.set_index([df.groupby("Stage").cumcount(), "Stage"])['Value']\
  .unstack().astype(int)\
  .eval("Ratio = B / A").assign(Desc="B/A")
```

Output:

```
Stage  A  B  Ratio Desc
0      3  0    0.0  B/A
1      2  4    2.0  B/A
```